# Managing migrations while moving from default taggit tags to taggit custom tags

Tags: django, tags, django-taggit

I was working on adding Tags to Articles, Comments using `django-taggit`.

But now I need the Tags to be associated with Account - so every `tag` must be tied to an `account_id` and only Articles, Comments of that Account can access these tags.

To achieve this, I had to implement a CustomTag.

In between these two stages, there were few other migrations relavant to other models. Example

```
0021_add_tags_to_articles_and_comments.py
0022_some_other_model_migration.py
0023_some_other_model_migration.py
0024_use_custom_tag_with_custom_taggedobject.py
```

Taggit documentation mentions the below to remove the tables taggit created and using custom tags

[image]

But this is messing up with my initial migration that added taggit tables because `0021_add_tags_to_articles_and_comments.py` has dependencies

```
    dependencies = [
        (
            "taggit",
            "0006_rename_taggeditem_content_type_object_id_taggit_tagg_content_8fc721_idx",
        ),
        ("blog_app", "0020_blog"),
    ]
```

I cant delete all the migrations and redo them because these changes are being used in current app.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Apologies if the question doesn't seem well explained.